# JavaScript usage of 'const' inside for-loop body ? (I am confused)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, constants

How can the same 'const' be initialized multiple times in a for-loop? I thought 'const' can only be initialized once. I'm a beginning developer.

Does the const element get deleted each iteration and have to be redeclared?
After a for-loop iteration loops each time, are all variables that were in its body deleted/lost?

```
const constDiv = document.createElement('div');

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    const element = document.createElement('p');
    element.textContent = 'This is paragraph number ' + i;

    element.addEventListener('click', function respondClick(event) {
        console.log('A <p> was clicked');
    });

    constDiv.appendChild(element);
}

document.body.appendChild(constDiv);
```

Comment: `const` is [**block scoped**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#block_scoping). The body of the `for` loop is a block

Comment: Does this mean that after each iteration of the for loop, the const <in the body of the for-loop> is deleted before it runs again? That way, each declaration is considered the first time it is being declared?

Comment: "*Does the const element get deleted each iteration?*" - no, they persist as long as something is still referencing them. (In your case, nothing). "*Does it have to be redeclared?*" - yes, every iteration starts with a fresh, empty block scope.

Comment: So as long as you have different block scopes, you can declare the same const over and over? like

{ const a = 5; }
{ const a = 7; }
{ const a = "string";}  ? 

What do you mean by referencing? I thought you couldn't reference a const outside of its scope?

As always - thank you for all the replies

Comment: Yes, you can reference it only from within its scope, but for example if you had written `console.log('This was clicked:', element);` in your event handler, the variable would have been referenced by the function, which persists even after the loop ends. This is known as a [*closure*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572), and means the variables don't (necessarily) get destroyed at the end of each iteration.

Comment: "*So as long as you have different block scopes, you can declare the same const over and over?*" - yes, exactly. They're different variables, with different values, with the same name but different scopes.